# I want to Capture HTTPS Traffic from app but it does not work

Tags: post, capture

I want to capture HTTPS Traffic For App Called Dofus Touch url : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ankama.dofustouch
Someone please can give me POST data and URL ....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

I found it worked really great for capturing HTTPS traffic of apps at work.

Comment: Yes I have tried it but when I write data in the application it does not appear in fiddler ...

Comment: I have already tried Windows App and Application Android but not work

Comment: If you're on macOS. I highly suggest Proxyman.io because it's comprehensive guideline to intercept HTTPS Request on Android Device.